# Instant apps sized under 4MB

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps

Can an app whose download size is already below 4MB be distributed also as an instant app without modification?

Answer (score 2):

There are still steps to take to make the app available as an instant app. See http://g.co/instantapps

For a sample of a single feature module instant app [see this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello-kotlin).

But the app size doesn't have to be reduced further.